# Add 2 values together in PHP with Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, screen-scraping, return-value, addition

I am scraping a value using "simple html dom" and then would like to add an additional value to that from what the user inputs. Below is my what I have but I can't get the two variables to add up. Any Help would be great!

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> " method="post">

  New Price: <input type="text" name="eagle" size="5" /><br/>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /><br/><br/>
 </form>

 <?php

 include('includes/simple_html_dom.php');

 $html = file_get_html('http://apmex.com/');

  $metals_main = $html->find('.table-invest tbody tr td', 1)->innertext;
  echo " 1 oz = " .$metals_main. '<br>';


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $maple = $_POST['eagle']; 
   $resmaple = $maple + $metals_main;
   echo '<br>'. '<div class="eagles">'. " 1 oz " . '<br>' .$resmaple. '</div>';

   }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `http://apmex.com/` website, the value at `'.table-invest tbody tr td', 1` is `$1,307.40`. Which is a formatted currency. In order to do calculations with this value, you need to unformat that.

For PHP 5.3+ You can use [NumberFormatter.parseCurrency](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) for this purpose. Otherwise you may try regular expressions.

If you have PHP 5.3 and have PECL intl installed:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$resample = $maple + $formatter->parseCurrency($metals_main, $curr);
```

Otherwise:

```
$unformatted_metals_main = intval(preg_replace('@[$.,]@', '', $metals_main)) / 100;
$resample = $maple + $unformatted_metals_main;
```